# Get correct powercli's result to Ansible register

Tags: ansible, powercli

Hello everyone~ I have a question.

Firstly..I can not speak English very well.

Actually I have some problem...
I want add new NIC to GuestVM by powercli.
And then I want get MacAddress of new NIC on my GuestVM and I tried to save my register variable.

==================================================

< My Ansible Code >

```
---
- name:
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:

  - name: Get new NIC MacAddress
    shell: |
      Connect-VIServer -Server '$my_vCenter' -User $my_ID -Password '$my_PWD' | Out-null
      $vm = get-vm | where { $_.ExtensionData.config.uuid -eq $my_UUID }
      $nic = New-NetworkAdapter -VM $vm -NetworkName "vmnet_10.40.95.x" -WakeOnLan -StartConnected
      $nic.MacAddress

    args:
      executable: /usr/bin/pwsh
    register: new_macaddress
    delegate_to: localhost

  - debug:
      var: new_macaddress.stdout_lines
```

====================================================================

However, My register variable's result is not good.

====================================================================

< register variable result >

```
{
    "changed": false,
    "_ansible_verbose_always": true,
    "new_macaddress.stdout_lines": [
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "                      00:50:56:8a:69:11"
    ],
    "_ansible_no_log": false
}
```

====================================================================

I want only MacAddress (00:50:56:8a:69:11), but there are many unnessesary things. (For example : "", "", "",......)

So, I wonder that how I can get only macaddress.

Please, help me T_T

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might have some other networks adapters that are powered off. They give blank results, so try just the one you need.

```
$nic1 = $nic | where {$_.NetworkName -eq "vmnet_10.40.95.x"}
$nic1.macaddress
```